# DrupalDatabaseCache is causing performance issues

Tags: caching, performance

I have devel query log / page execution time enabled on my site and most of the queries which are slowing down my site are related to DrupalDatebaseCache.

> DrupalDatabaseCache::set

**Sample Query :**

> UPDATE cache SET serialized=:db_update_placeholder_0,
>   created=:db_update_placeholder_1, expire=:db_update_placeholder_2,
>   data=:db_update_placeholder_3 WHERE ( (cid =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_0) )
>
> INSERT INTO cache_menu (cid, serialized, created, expire, data) VALUES
>   (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_4)

Any clue what drupal is doing with caching and how to minimize it .
thanks

**####Update####**

I installed Memcache but still DrupalDatabaseCache calls are being made which is making the site slow .

[image]
[image]

Comment: How to _minimize_ caching? That's not a good idea. The less you cache, the more resources will be used to prepare page content. The simple answer is get your site on better hardware, and/or configure the application servers correctly for your app

Comment: thanks. Okay what if i move the site to a better hardware and result are not satisfactory. can you please suggest a way where i can benchmark my site before upgrading hardware.

Comment: [XHProf](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) is the easiest way to profile a PHP app in my experience, there's also a [Drupal integration module](https://drupal.org/project/XHProf). But you'll need to know how to interpret the results, not something we can teach you here I'm afraid. If it helps I'm running a 2.3 core i7 with 16gb ram and every site absolutely flies. Your mileage will vary depending on your exact situation of course, but basically get yourself the best computer you can afford.

Comment: Yes, yes it is causing performance issues. Databases are not the greatest caches around. But what is your question, exactly?

Comment: my question was to reduce the time DrupalDatabaseCache functions are causing. I was advised to configure memcache but memcache does not help in removing (reducing ) "DrupalDatabaseCache " queries in my case.

Comment: Both memcache modules ([1](https://drupal.org/project/memcache), [2](https://drupal.org/project/memcache_storage)) require a bit of configuration to take effect. If it's not there, they cannot help. If it is there, you should post it so we could analyze it and tell what's wrong. But please **don't [chameleon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/225745) this question**.

Comment: @brainHax I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what caching is/ how it works - changing the storage method couldn't possibly reduce the number of cache _queries_, that was never the aim of advising you to do that. The point of an in-memory cache is that it provides **quicker** storage/retrieval than the same thing coming from a database. You cannot reduce the number of cache queries without changing core code, simple as that. And if you do, your app will be slower because you're not caching any more. If your memory access is as slow as your disk access, you need a new computer!

Comment: @Mołot, i understand the questions is flowing in to many directions. I will try to not "chameleon" my future questions.
Clive, okay.. but Felix Eve said in his last second last comment that he don't see "INSERT INTO cache" queries at all with memcache enabled/configured

Comment: @brainHax Well yeah, presumably you have `$conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';` in your settings.php file? What did you think that did, exactly? :P

Comment: (BTW, you don't want the form cache in memory, it can get massive)

Comment: @Clive. I am not able to get what this does  actually $conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';
So where is the problem ? my memcache configs ? will i be able to reduce the Queries deadlocks in below snapshot. ? :( http://i.stack.imgur.com/hiWm0.jpg

Comment: That line says to Drupal "when you're looking for the `cache_form` bin, get it from the database, not from the default which is set as memcache". You can try removing that line so cache_form is stored in memory, but the form cache is slightly different than the other bins, and general advice is to keep it in the database, or user's form submission experiences might be volatile. You can probably get away with it in memory on a dev site, but definitely don't do it on prod

Comment: Great. Now i dont see Cache Queries to database. Thanks Clive for the suggestions i understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you concerned with performance then you want to maximise caching, not minimise it!

Caching is used to store data once expensive (time consuming) processes have been used to prepare it. Then future page requests simply return the cached data and don't have to do the slow processing again.

By default Drupal stores it's cache in the database but as you've spotted this isn't always that fast. Using a module like [APC](https://drupal.org/project/apc) or [memcache](https://drupal.org/project/memcache) allows you to store the cache in the servers memory, as opposed to having to write it to the DB so this is much faster.

To make the most of Druapl's caching functions I would also recommend taking a read of lullabot's excellent article: [A Beginner's Guide to Caching Data in Drupal 7](https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/beginners-guide-caching-data-drupal-7)

Comment: [Redis](https://drupal.org/project/redis) is also a very good option

Comment: actually my site is still in dev. and the caching Queires are making the development slower day by day . (i keep on adding modules every once a while when needed ) . and devel reported that most of the time caching queries were taking. reset of the modules were doing fine . On a clean install of drupal the caching queries are not that much. (dev has couple of nodes only for testing)

Comment: I have already installed memcache, configured and dedicated 1.5 GB memory. Still drupal is executing queries mentioned in question in large numbers.

Comment: Hmm, you must have not set up memcache correctly then. I'm using it and with query logging enabled and I have no "INSERT INTO cache" queries at all. Have you altered settings.php to set your cache_backends, cache_default_class and cache_class_cache_form?

Comment: As an example [I have these lines](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AvyR1Hmk) in my settings.php.

Comment: Yes every thing is configured fine. i have same config settings. Server is listening and showing stats. Mostly cache queries are on frontend. Drupal admin is not showing MUCH cache insert/update queries 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9veotmqfthg4ec/stats_mem.jpg
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yp9aaq8v23uzo5b/memcache.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Getting memcache working correctly is the right answer. I'm leaving a link here for people who don't have the option of installing memcache and are looking for a solution: [Fixes for MySQL Deadlocks in D7](https://groups.drupal.org/node/415883)